# nuget pack "Illegal characters in path" on a path with spaces

Tags: c#, path, nuget, character, pack

I have been trying to create a nuget package to push to our software and getting this error message.

COMMAND:
C:\Users\Nathan\source\repos\Connex Online.nuget>nuget pack "C:\Users\Nathan\source\repos\Connex Online\PlatformSupport\WooCommerce\WooCommerce.Core" -Prop Configuration=Debug -IncludeReferencedProjects -Prop Platform=AnyCP

MESSAGE:
Illegal characters in path.

Recently we have

- switched from Azure Devops to Git
- cloned a new repository to use moving forward
- downloaded the most recent stable version of nuget (v 5.10.0)
- tried using ascii characters where "Connex Online" is located in the file pathway (Connex%20Online) but got same result.

any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Azure DevOps is a host and Git a tool. Do you want say Azure DevOps to GitHub or TFVC to Git?

Answer (score 1):

finally got the nuget pack command to work.

1. typo in end of command(Platform=AnyCP --> Platform=AnyCPU)
2. upgraded to newest nuget.exe (v 5.10.0)
3. encased the file path in quotation marks

> nuget pack **"C:\Users\Nathan\source\repos\Connex Online\PlatformSupport\WooCommerce\WooCommerce.Core"** -Prop Configuration=Debug -IncludeReferencedProjects -Prop Platform=AnyCPU